# How to perform same event on two different buttons?

Tags: php

I have this piece of code below, supposing it will display no request when no data in database and it will display the request with an accept and reject button when they is data in database. How should i write my code in order to make the accept and reject button perform some action?

```
<?php 

        $travelRequest = $user->userTravelRequest($userid);
        if(!$travelRequest){
            echo '<div class="requestbox">
                  <p> You have no request from others at the moment. </p>
                  </div>';
        }

        else {
            foreach($travelRequest as $request){

                echo '<div class= "requestbox">
                      <p>'. $request->trip_name.'</p>
                      <p>Organised by '.$request->username.'</p>';

        ?>

                      <form method="POST">
                      <div class = "AR-btn">
                      <input type="button" name="accept" value="Accept"/>
                      <input type="button" name="reject" value="Reject"/>
                      <p></p>
                      </div>
                      </form>
                      </div>

        <?php   

            }

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You need to write Javascript for the actions. You can then put a call to the JS function in the `onclick` attributes.

Comment: @Barmar Not necessarily. OP can change that to two forms where the submit buttons have a different name and then do the logic in the PHP file

Comment: @user4815740 you just need to check you button was submitted and to do anything you want.  Also you need to add the action in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Use `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`, and give them the same name. Then they'll submit the form, and the script can test which button was used from the value of that parameter.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Accept"/>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Reject"/>
```

You then test this with:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Accept') {
        // Add to database
    } elseif ($_POST['action'] == 'Reject') {
        // Delete from database
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally at least one `type="hidden"` field is probably necessary to determine which of the trips is concerned

Comment: True. That would be necessary even with just one button, so it's an independent issue.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['action'])` show when you click on one of the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['accept']) && $_POST['accept'] == 'Accept' ) {
    // do what you want
     die("Accept is clicked");
} else if (isset($_POST['reject']) && $_POST['reject'] == 'Reject' ) {
    // do what you want
    die("Reject is clicked");
}
?>
<?php
        $travelRequest = $user->userTravelRequest($userid);
        if(!$travelRequest){
            echo '<div class="requestbox">
                  <p> You have no request from others at the moment. </p>
                  </div>';
        } else {

            foreach($travelRequest as $request){
                echo '<div class= "requestbox">
                      <p>'. $request->trip_name.'</p>
                      <p>Organised by '.$request->username.'</p>'; 

        ?>
              <form method="POST">
                  <div class = "AR-btn">
                      <input type="submit" name="accept" value="Accept"/>
                      <input type="submit" name="reject" value="Reject"/>
                  <p></p>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
        <?php
            }
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this logic..may help you

```
$query = "select data from database";
    .
    .
    .


 $data = $row['data'];

    if($data){  // reject button when they is data in database
       echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Reject"/>';
    }
    else{ // viceversa
       echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Accept"/>';
    }
```